# iOS - undefined symbols for architecture arm7, arm64

Tags: ios, xcode, socketscan

I looking at a older iOS project I haven't done anything with for a while and I need to update the SDK for a scanner so it is 64 bit.
I added the files for the scanner kit (drag and drop) into the project but now when I build I get the error 
undefined symbols for architecture armv7

It was referring to arm64 but I tried a couple of things and now it's referring to armv7 (setting other linker flags and editing the basic build settings).

My build settings are:
Architecture: standard
Base SDK  8.4
Build active architecture only: no
Valid architectures: armv7 armv7s arm64

The output from building is:

Ld /Users/meetingroom/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-apetpmawlnpfonginyycjwqagzuc/Build/Intermediates/xxx.build/Debug-iphoneos/xxx.build/Objects-normal/armv7/xxxx normal armv7
    cd "/Users/meetingroom/Documents/iOS Projects/xxx Project/xxx iOS8"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk -L/Users/meetingroom/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-apetpmawlnpfonginyycjwqagzuc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/meetingroom/Documents/iOS\ Projects/xxx\ Project/xxx\ iOS8/xxx/ScanAPI/lib -F/Users/meetingroom/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-apetpmawlnpfonginyycjwqagzuc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/meetingroom/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-apetpmawlnpfonginyycjwqagzuc/Build/Intermediates/xxx.build/Debug-iphoneos/xxx.build/Objects-normal/armv7/xxx.LinkFileList -dead_strip -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -stdlib=libc++ -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -framework AudioToolbox -framework ExternalAccessory -lsqlite3.0 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lScanApi -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/meetingroom/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-apetpmawlnpfonginyycjwqagzuc/Build/Intermediates/xxx.build/Debug-iphoneos/xxx.build/Objects-normal/armv7/xxx_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/meetingroom/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-apetpmawlnpfonginyycjwqagzuc/Build/Intermediates/xxx.build/Debug-iphoneos/xxxx.build/Objects-normal/armv7/xxx

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode", referenced from:
      -[SoftScanController initWithDeviceObject:] in libScanApi.a(SoftScanController.o)
  "_AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code", referenced from:
      -[SoftScanController initWithDeviceObject:] in libScanApi.a(SoftScanController.o)
  "_AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code", referenced from:
      -[SoftScanController initWithDeviceObject:] in libScanApi.a(SoftScanController.o)
  "_AVMediaTypeVideo", referenced from:
      -[SoftScan initWithDelegate:] in libScanApi.a(SoftScanController.o)
  "_AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode", referenced from:
      -[SoftScanController initWithDeviceObject:] in libScanApi.a(SoftScanController.o)
  "_AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code", referenced from:
      -[SoftScanController initWithDeviceObject:] in libScanApi.a(SoftScanController.o)
  "_AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill", referenced from:
      -[SoftScan start:] in libScanApi.a(SoftScanController.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libScanApi.a(SoftScanController.o)
  "_AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code", referenced from:
      -[SoftScanController initWithDeviceObject:] in libScanApi.a(SoftScanController.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libScanApi.a(SoftScanController.o)
  "_AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code", referenced from:
      -[SoftScanController initWithDeviceObject:] in libScanApi.a(SoftScanController.o)
  "_AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code", referenced from:
      -[SoftScanController initWithDeviceObject:] in libScanApi.a(SoftScanController.o)
  "_AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode", referenced from:
      -[SoftScanController initWithDeviceObject:] in libScanApi.a(SoftScanController.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureMetadataOutput", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libScanApi.a(SoftScanController.o)
  "_AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Mod43Code", referenced from:
      -[SoftScanController initWithDeviceObject:] in libScanApi.a(SoftScanController.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureDeviceInput", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libScanApi.a(SoftScanController.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureDevice", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libScanApi.a(SoftScanController.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The only errors are related to the SDK but I confirmed that I have installed that 64 bit version.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The latest release uses cocoapods to add the SDK to your project. Is that the version you are using or do you have the version right before that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how I posted this question up twice but it was answered here ([XCode - undefined symbols for architecture armv7 arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33118104/xcode-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7-arm64/33118653#33118653)) .
In brief I hadn't linked the AVFoundation in my project.