# XCode - undefined symbols for architecture armv7 arm64

Tags: ios, xcode

I've gone to an older project that needs to have the SDK updated for the scanner that it uses. The new SDK is 64bit ready and so the app needs updating.
The SDK is installed by dragging and dropping into the project but after that I get the following error when building:

Note: I was getting an error referring to `arm64` but this one currently says `armv7` because I fiddled.

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>   "_AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode", referenced from:
>         -[SoftScanController initWithDeviceObject:] in libScanApi.a(SoftScanController.o)   "_AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code",
>   referenced from:
>         -[SoftScanController initWithDeviceObject:] in libScanApi.a(SoftScanController.o)
>   "_AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code", referenced from:
>         -[SoftScanController initWithDeviceObject:] in libScanApi.a(SoftScanController.o)   "_AVMediaTypeVideo", referenced
>   from:
>         -[SoftScan initWithDelegate:] in libScanApi.a(SoftScanController.o)   "_AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode",
>   referenced from:
>         -[SoftScanController initWithDeviceObject:] in libScanApi.a(SoftScanController.o)   "_AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code",
>   referenced from:
>         -[SoftScanController initWithDeviceObject:] in libScanApi.a(SoftScanController.o)
>   "_AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill", referenced from:
>         -[SoftScan start:] in libScanApi.a(SoftScanController.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libScanApi.a(SoftScanController.o)   "_AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code", referenced from:
>         -[SoftScanController initWithDeviceObject:] in libScanApi.a(SoftScanController.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureSession",
>   referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libScanApi.a(SoftScanController.o)   "_AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code", referenced from:
>         -[SoftScanController initWithDeviceObject:] in libScanApi.a(SoftScanController.o)
>   "_AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code", referenced from:
>         -[SoftScanController initWithDeviceObject:] in libScanApi.a(SoftScanController.o)   "_AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode",
>   referenced from:
>         -[SoftScanController initWithDeviceObject:] in libScanApi.a(SoftScanController.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureMetadataOutput", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libScanApi.a(SoftScanController.o)   "_AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Mod43Code", referenced from:
>         -[SoftScanController initWithDeviceObject:] in libScanApi.a(SoftScanController.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureDeviceInput", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libScanApi.a(SoftScanController.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureDevice", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libScanApi.a(SoftScanController.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

All of the errors that come up refer to the SDK for the scanner.
My current build settings are:

**Architectures**: `Standard architecture`

**`Base SDK: latest(9.0)`**

**`Build Active architecture only : no`**

**`valid architectures: armv7 armv7s arm64`**

Any assistance would be well received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are not linking your project with the `AVFoundation` framework.

[User Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html).

Comment: So simple. Thank you.