# Cocoapods OpenSSL undefined symbols arm64

Tags: ios, xcode, openssl, cocoapods

I'm trying to use OpenSSL in my project through Cocoapods, but it just keeps failing on some "undefined symbols for arm64".
While I know that this question had been asked before; **I can't get it to work using the provided solutions**. It's really and I mean *really* frustrating.

I tried the solutions posted in:

- [Undefined symbols for architecture arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64)
- [XCode - undefined symbols for architecture armv7 arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33118104/xcode-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7-arm64)

All the things I did and the configs:

- Tried building with the `Build Active Architectures` for both Debug and Release to `YES` and tried it with both for `NO` (in My Project, the Pods project and all the Targets)
- Tried building with the `Valid architectures` to `arm64 arm7 arm7s` and all possible variations you can think of with those three
- My project has the linker flags and library/framework search paths set to `$(inherited)`
- Removed duplicate linker flags or library/framework search paths
- I have added the Pods-{My Project} lib to My project
- Re-installed all the pods by:

  - Deleting all installed pods
  - Deleting the Podfile
  - Called `pod init`
  - Added each pod one step at a time
- Re-added the target in My Project and did all the steps again

Next to the above list I probably did a lot of other things I cannot even remember through my clouded-vision right now.

Now this is how my project is set up:

I have a main project which builds my framework. Now because I use both SQLCipher and OpenSSL and had the *transitive dependencies* error, I added a static library target to my project. This static library target has the Cocoapods dependencies for SQLCipher and OpenSSL which enabled me to use `use_frameworks` for the framework target in my project.

So far so good and everything works fine, but whenever I try to use OpenSSL in my static library it complains about the godforsaken undefined symbols. I can't seem to resolve those.

Does anyone knows what goes wrong? Or are there other/better setups for what I'm trying?

Comment: How are you cross-compiling OpenSSL for arm64? Also, be very careful about using other's build systems for OpenSSL. Each OpenSSL configuration gets its own `<opensslconf.h>` and `<bn.h>`. I seem to recall CocoaPods was not doing things it needed to. Also see [Build Multiarch OpenSSL on OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25530429/608639).

Comment: Hm, I've used the OpenSSL cocoapod (https://cocoapods.org/pods/OpenSSL) and the OpenSSL-for-ios (https://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone). Are they both 'wrong'? And if so how do I add OpenSSL to My Project then?

Comment: I'm guessing they are probably both wrong. I would need to see their `<opensslconf.h>` and `<bn.h>` to be certain.

Comment: I see, no idea where to get those. Could I bother you in private?

Comment: @Ge3.E - I looked at, for example, the OpenSSL 1.0.2 build script at [OpenSSL.podspec](https://github.com/FredericJacobs/OpenSSL-Pod/blob/master/1.0.208/OpenSSL.podspec). *If* that's all they are doing, then its using the same `<opensslconf.h>` and `<bn.h>` for all architectures. I'm fairly certain its wrong. I thought I filed a bug report against them for it some time ago, but I can't locate it.

Comment: That's probably the source of the problems as well then. What can one do to compile it himself? _Someone_ should be able to create a pod which is compatible with all iOS archs right?